# What is the criteria to choose between PTC thermistor and resettable fuse (PPTC)?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, protection, fuses, overheat

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resettable_fuse) states:

> (PPTC) are similar in function to PTC thermistors in certain situations but operate on mechanical changes instead of charge carrier effects in semiconductors.

Another [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor#PTC) says there is no strict boundary.

> "Another type of PTC thermistor is the polymer PTC, which is sold under brand names such as "Polyswitch"

Is there really a difference to understand or am I just wasting my way in termininolgy?

Answer (score 2):

It's really the difference between a PTC thermistor in which self heating is undesirable since it affects accurate measurement of whatever the thermistor is supposed to measure and a polyfuse in which self heating is desirable since it gives a sharper trip point and maintains the device in a high-resistance state until power is removed for some time.